# SQL Server Agent - The AcquireConnection method failed - Excel files from another network drive

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

I am getting an error

> The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "ConnectionManagerName" failed with error code 0xC0202009

while running the package from SQL Server Agent.

The Excel files are from another server and I have specified the user and password in the the Integration Services Catalogs> SSISBD > Package > Configure dialog (please see the attached screen below) as well as created and used an SQL Agent proxy account but it's not helping.

If I copy the Excel files to the server where the package is running then there is no error so it's sure that the problem is in connecting to another server.

[image]

Could someone please assist me in resolving this error?

Best Wishes,

Prakash